# The Walking Dead has no CD key

Tags: steam, the-walking-dead-season-one

I bought the CD version of The Walking Dead and realized there is no CD key printed anywhere. I'd like to play it on Steam and earn achievements, so are the CD version and the Steam version different?

Comment: Did you buy it used?  Where did you get it from?

Comment: I don't think so, I bought it from a store which I have bought many other games from that have working CD keys.

Comment: You may want to bring the game back to them, and see what they say about not having a CD key.

Comment: The cashier opens the case for everyone who buys a game. She was also as confused as I did.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the CD version (and the version you can buy for download directly from Telltale) is separate from the Steam version. If you didn't buy the Steam version then you can't add it to Steam and earn the achievements.

Comment: Yah, there's no general requirement that PC games sold in retail boxes come with Steam keys, even if that game is available on Steam. Generally boxed games that do include Steam keys will list Steam as a requirement on the back of the box. Often they'll say that accepting the Steam Subscriber Agreement is necessary to play the game.

Comment: @RossRidge You're right, my copy of TWD does not have Steam listed as a requirement. However, and not sure if this helps anything at all, there is a small 7-digit code printed at the lower left corner of a booklet. Does it mean anything?

Comment: @MegaRodeon: Doubtful. Some publishers are either kind enough to include a steam key (even if steam isn't required) or provide some way of getting a steam key. Most do not. I know I had a boxed copy of Race 07 and it had a steam key printed inside the box.

Comment: Also a quick search brings up: http://www.telltalegames.com/community/discussion/51581/steam-key I have a number of TTG games direct from TTG that I can't add to Steam. I have a handful of others that I bought via Steam that are on Steam.